# Firefox Wont Keep Session info in ajax Post request

Tags: ajax, session, firefox

i'm working on upload site in c# i'm currently using uploadify flash Uploader with ASP.NET
when i upload my file The session information in firefox is empty but in other browser chrome opera safari ie working fine uploadify send post request which cause problem in session
Any Solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem by using little technique 
i have add encrypted username at the end of upload when request send to upload page the upload page will decrypt username if it's not successful then don't perform upload

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

                       $(function() {

                           $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                               'formData'     : {
                               },
                               'fileSizeLimit': '20000KB',
                               'buttonClass': 'mybtn',
                               'swf'      : '../assets/uploadify.swf',
                               'uploader': 'upload.aspx?u={i add encrypted username here}',
                               'uploadLimit' : 20
                           });
                       });
                    </script>
```